# Cassandra: Column Family with composite key

Tags: cassandra

I need to create in Cassandra a Column Family (PlayerGoals) with a composite key (Player,Match)
I was thinking to define this as a Supercolumn but i read its not a good idea to use Supercolumns.

An example of what i need to represent would be:

PlayerGoals:

```
Player: 1
    Match: 2
        Goals - 0
    Match: 3
        Goals - 2
Player: 2
    Match: 2 
        Goals - 1
```

....

Comment: Can you please mention your querying pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can store this using a composite key, where the key is Player:Match, as follows:

```
1:2
  Goals = 0
1:3
  Goals = 2
2:2
  Goals = 1
```

With this schema you can:

- Get all matches for a player
- Get highest/lowest/etc goals for a player
- Find out which of a group of players participated in a match
- Sort a list of known players by number of goals scored

You need a separate index to:

- Get players for a match
- Rank unknown players

Comment: First of all thanks, actually my question was how to do these in Cassandra.
So i thought to create these Column Families..

create column family Player
with comparator = UTF8Type
and default_validation_class = UTF8Type
and column_metadata = [
         {column_name : Name, validation_class : UTF8Type}
];

create column family Match
with comparator = UTF8Type
and default_validation_class = UTF8Type
and column_metadata = [
         {column_name : MatchName, validation_class : UTF8Type}
];

Comment: create column family PlayerMatch
with comparator = 'CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type)'
and default_validation_class = UTF8Type
and column_metadata = [
         {column_name : Goals, validation_class : UTF8Type}
];


if i insert this 2 rows:
set Player['01'][utf8('Name')]=utf8('Peter Crouch');
set Match['01'][utf8('MatchName')]=utf8('FA Cup 01');

How can i insert a row in PlayerMatch using the rows added before? (set PlayerMatch['???']['???'][utf8('Goals')]=utf8('2');)
thanks in advance.